# JSON response data type is not uniform

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, response, postgresql-9.3

I have AJax call as below using JS .I am using Knockout JS

```
 var someManager = new AjaxManager('/YYYYYY/XXX/list');
        CommonUtils.dispWaitPopup();
        // someManager List addLoadCallback()
        someManager.addLoadCallback(function (data) {
            self.YYYList = ko.observableArray(data.YYYYList);
            var viewModel = new ProjectViewModel(data);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            CommonUtils.closeWaitPopup();
        });
        var startDate = new Date();
        startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 3);
        var endDate = new Date();
        var param = {
            'startDate': moment(startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
            'closeDate': moment(endDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
        };
        someManager.request(param);
```

Datas are fetched from Postgres DB. For particular Numeric field (Example charging rate at back end is having values as 1.00 but Ajax response simply ignore trailing zeros after decimal point by treating it as Numeric . Ironically  for some other AJAX call same data (rate ) is returned as String "1.00". I am very much puzzled how same record is returned as Numeric for one Ajax response as well as String for other AJAX call response. Result is coming from same table and same column value.

Comment: If the server is building the JSON response, that's where the problem would be.

Comment: From server side the same data type is used for both Ajax calls. That is String value is passed from server side. But some how client side it is getting auto converted to Numeric as well as String for both calls

Comment: You'll have to use the browser "Network" developer tool to examine the actual JSON.

Comment: Yes I got the issue. The issue from Controller/Service(from Server) side we are using HashMap<String,Object> to store the response. In HashMap all values are stored. After converting this particular field to String from Server side issue gets resolved. I wonder from Postgres DB this field is numeric data type with 2 digit precision after decimal . In Java it is auto converted as "Big decimal" by MYBATIS framework. How json simply treat this as Object .If JSON treats this as plain object why trailing zeros are ignored? any specific reason??

Comment: AFAIK you should applyBindings only once, not every ajaxcall, it should be enogh to update the observableArray to get the "content refresh" ...regarding your question just use `parseFloat(x)`